# Adding new NFTs to an already established collection?

Tags: nft, token

I am looking to setup a collection on the solana blockchain. The idea is that when a real world watch is sold, the buyer receives an nft validating this purchase with the appropriate metadata (time of purchase, watch details, name etc). However, my question is if it is possible to add new nfts to an already created collection as each watch is purchased? Thanks

Comment: consider editing the description to improve focus.  the example doesn't seem pertinent and distracts from the core question

Answer (score 1):

If i assume you are using the candy machine, no you cannot add NFTs defined by the candy machine ID as the size is predefined on initialization.

If you are talking about the Collection metaplex standard, yes you can add NFTs to a collection at any time.

You can set a collection while minting the NFT with `CreateMetadataAccountArgsV3` https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/3a9c68ab8c48318f96379a136feaa9b66c322752/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs#L82

then verify it `VerifyCollection` https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/3a9c68ab8c48318f96379a136feaa9b66c322752/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs#L347

or set and verify on an already created NFT which doesn't have the collection set `SetAndVerifyCollection` https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/3a9c68ab8c48318f96379a136feaa9b66c322752/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs#L428

Comment: Please be more specific on why a user can not do that with Candy Machine. In my opinion i think it's possible if the CM was created with following the MCC standard which nowdays most of the sugar CMV2 Collections are.